# How do I get the Condor VTOL out of the park for the related vehicle delivery mission?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I have attempted this particular vehicle theft mission at least a half dozen times now.  I have to raid a STAG outpost that mysteriously popped up inside of one of the city's parks, and steal a Condor VTOL, and fly it to the airport.

The problem is that this vehicle is made from papier-mâché.  If it isn't already smoking by the time I fly out of the park, random police and STAG soldiers shooting at it quickly get it to that point.  I can eventually get up high enough to be outside the range of small arms fire, but then when I try to land at the airport, enough soldiers have already massed there that they put the final few bullet holes in the plane and I smash into the delivery point in a charred mass of metal and phallic weaponry.

What's the trick to this vehicle theft?

Comment: This is the Condor, isn't it, not the Falcon?

Comment: You might be right.  I'll double check, but if you find that it is, feel free to edit.

Comment: It is ... fortunately there's only one person who wants a VTOL. I've nearly landed it once, but I'd like to do it for sure and then make sure it works the way I think before posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've reached respect level 20, you can buy [Notoriety Wipe: Police](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Upgrades#Notoriety) from the Upgrade Store.  This adds a number to your cell phone's contact list which, as the name implies, completely removes your police notoriety when called.

Call that number as soon as you enter the Falcon and your notoriety spikes — you'll be able to fly off at your leisure, unmolested by local law enforcement.  Avoid causing any property damage along the way, and you'll be allowed to land peacefully, as well.

Comment: Gah, I feel like I knew this, but I wonder why I didn't use it?  I think I might have used up my notoriety wipe on another vehicle delivery and was just impatient.  Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @agent86 — Don't feel too bad… I haven't yet found a happy medium between "constantly waste it on trivial things" and "forget I have it".  ;-)

Comment: It is also possible without Notoriety Wipe if you play coop. I was also having problems and had my coop friend distract (or kill) the enemies as best as he could. But I also needed at least five attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I completed the game's Campaign (missions). And that place was still there even though STAG was evicted from Steelport. There are two Condors and an F-69 parked there. No STAG soldiers or anything. Took one for Vehicle Theft and one for myself.

Comment: Tris, this isn't like a traditional message board. The space here is reserved for answers to the original question. Do ask a question using the Ask Question button in the upper right if you have any though!

Comment: @authenticgeek seems to me this does indeed answer the question, by suggesting to do this quest after the campaign completes.

Comment: @Oak Seemed like an anecdote first time I read it but I see the answer part now.

Answer (score 1):

Without using the "police forgiveness" perk, I was able to get the Condor out of there by immediately switching to fixed-wing mode and then flying low through the skyscrapers; this somehow prevented me from picking up random ground fire.  It was a close-run thing once I got to the airport & the soldiers massed there, but doable.

Answer (score -1):

First off its not considered an aircraft, its considered a helicopter. I was able to get it by getting my police notoriety up to lvl 5 while standing in front of the sunset park crib then calling my own helicopter and landing on top of the building next to the saints crib with the helipad in sunset park, then kept shooting f-69's until i saw a condor and used the r/c controller to land it next to me on the rooftop and hopped in. since i was next door to the crib landing it on the helipad and adding it to my collection without getting too much damage was cake.

Comment: Already answered, Jonkeau. Btw, Welcome to Arqade. *gets bored of greeting*