# How can I bring STAG back if I have 100% completion?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

There's a couple of the Saintsbook challenges that require you to have STAG forces available to kill.  After you complete the game, however, the STAG forces are nowhere to be found.  I believe that you can fight a few more STAG forces if you replay the final mission, but I think my save is glitched, so that's not an option.

Is there any way post-game completion to bring STAG back?  I miss their much nicer tanks and VTOLs for hijacking :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, but it depends on the progress you've made on Vehicle Thefts. If you haven't yet stolen the [VTOL Condor for BJ Barnes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/42068/8366), start that activity. That should spawn STAG troops in the park around the VTOLs that will magically appear there. Instead of running off with their precious little plane, just hang around and remove the forces who are <strike>blowing it up</strike> protecting it.

Comment: Sadly, I'm at 100% - I've done everything in the game :(  I don't suppose I can replay one of these missions?

Comment: I was afraid of that, based on the answers to your Condor question. (I wasn't sure exactly what the 100% covered, given that I'm not there myself.) No, I don't believe diversions are replayable. Have you tried co-op with someone who isn't at 100%? (I've played no co-op myself, so I can't say from experience.)

Answer (score 1):

You can not get STAG back unless you get DLC (for XBox 360) and you get STAG homies      (STAG commandos only). They will not drive STAG cars, but you will have STAG homies.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the stag condor vtol, the sunset park area of the game where stag was based still has a stag base.   There wont be any stag there but they have the Condor there so even if you 100% completed the game you can get one.   its in the parking area,  there's an abandoned stag base there.    As far as getting stag back,  no   once you 100 percent the game gangs and stag no longer spawn.

Answer (score 0):

The *Saints Row: The Third* Unlockable Pack ([Xbox 360, 160MSP](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Saints-Row-The-Third/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d8025451086d)) will give you all the things you didn't get as a result of your choices.

The other thing you can do is try to join someone who has STAG in their city and try the challenge then.

Answer (score 0):

If you're playing on the PC, you can install the **[Gentlemen of Steelport](http://idolninja.com/sr2.php)** mod compilation. One of its features is a 'Mission Replay' feature. The first mission that prominently pits you against [STAG](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/STAG) as an enemy is '[Gang Bang](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Gang_Bang)'. You can also choose to replay other [missions](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Missions_in_Saints_Row:_The_Third#Missions) where you are pitted against STAG.

Replaying a mission will set the world back to its original state during that mission. [Missions](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Missions_in_Saints_Row:_The_Third#Missions) after '[Gang Bang](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Gang_Bang)' will make STAG troops patrol the city again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the basic Stag vehicles in your garage you can turn those in for the vehicle theft challenge. I waited for hours for an N-forced to show up, only to have wasted my time. I took one out of the garage with the challenge active and it immediately told me to take it to the chop shop.